# уменьшить длину текста

Tags: html, css

Есть текст например:

> Оченьдлинныйтекст

Как уменьшить его длину, если текст не помещается на одной строке внутри дива, так чтобы лишнее было заменено на "..."? Например, чтобы стал такого вида:

> Оченьдлинн...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью **Javascript**, путем обрезки символов.

```js
    var text = "Очень длинный текст. Прям очень очень длинный";
    var croppedText = text.substring(0, 15) + "...";
    alert(croppedText);
```

Где 15 - число символов. **Результат**: Очень длинный т...

---

С помощью **Javascript**. Без потери слов.

```js
    function truncate(n, useWordBoundary) {
      var isTooLong = this.length > n,
        s_ = isTooLong ? this.substr(0, n - 1) : this;
      s_ = (useWordBoundary && isTooLong) ? s_.substr(0, s_.lastIndexOf(' ')) : s_;
      return isTooLong ? s_ + '...' : s_;
    };

    var s = 'Очень длинный текст. Прям очень очень длинный';
    alert(truncate.apply(s, [15, true]));
```

Где 15 - число символов. **Результат**: Очень длинный...

---

C помощью **CSS**

```css
.truncate {
  width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="truncate">
  Очень длинный текст. Прям очень очень длинный
</div>
```

Обрезаем по ширине блока. **Результат**: Очень длинный...

---

**P.S**. В качестве второго примера был взят код: [Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1199420/5910182). Удачного кодинга...

Answer (score 2):

Пример с http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-overflow

```css
p.clip {
    max-width:150px;
    white-space: nowrap; /* Запрещаем перенос строк */
    overflow: hidden; /* Обрезаем все, что не помещается в область */
    background: #fc0; /* Цвет фона */
    padding: 5px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Добавляем многоточие */
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>text-overflow</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p class="clip">Магнитное поле ничтожно гасит большой круг небесной сферы, 
  в таком случае эксцентриситеты и наклоны орбит возрастают.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```